# ¿Cómo puedo pasar datos de una clase a otra?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift

Básicamente tengo una encuesta que esta dividida en 4 `ViewController` que son : "Paso1",2,3 y 4 , en cada uno hay un checkbox que debería guardar un valor `booleano`, necesito guardar el dato de cada clase para ser usada al final para cargar un `viewController` con el resultado (por ejemplo si en las 4 pruebas dio  `[True, True, True , True]` cargará un `viewController` diciendo "Felicidades", en caso contrario `else` cargaría un `ViewController` diferente como intenta de nuevo.

Cualquier ayuda o información es bien recibida, muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas resuelve la pregunta planteada, deberías marcarla como respuesta correcta. No dejarla abandonada y seguir haciendo más preguntas. Saludos.

Comment: Si , hasta ahora que vuelvo me fijo en eso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución puede ser declarar una referencia dentro de cada ViewController, y antes de mandar a la siguiente pantalla agregar el valor de la respuesta con respecto al indice del paso en el que estas y luego al siguiente ViewController pasarle ese arreglo con el valor agregado para que en el paso final puedas leer todos los valores ingresados.

Otra solucion seria crear una clase Singleton, y ahi declarar el array cuando cambias de pantalla obtener la instancia de la clase y agregar el valor de respuesta.

Comment: el singleton funciono perfecto , gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quires se puede resolver fácilmente utilizando el método `prepareForSegue` de cada uno de tus `UIViewControllers` si es que estás utilizando un `UINavigationController`, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

> MyAwesomeStoryboard.storyboard

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> FirstViewController.swift

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var myAwesomeVar: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier where identifier == "SecondViewController" {
            guard let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController else {
                return
            }
            secondViewController.myAwesomeVar = self.myAwesomeVar
        }
    }

}
```

> SecondViewController.swift

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var myAwesomeVar: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier where identifier == "ThirdViewController" {
            guard let thirdViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ThirdViewController else {
                return
            }
            thirdViewController.myAwesomeVar = self.myAwesomeVar
        }
    }
}
```

Y así consecutivamente para todos los `UIViewControllers` que tengas.

Answer (score 0):

Creas un modelo de datos que sea por ejemplo un struct con los 4 valores que quieres guardar. Instancias el modelo, puede ser en el primer controlador. Haces lo que sea y el valor lo guardas en su sitio del modelo y le pasas el modelo al siguiente controlador, lo relleneas y se lo pasas al tercero y así hasta el último que tendras el modelo que será el struct con todos los datos de cada controlador.